# Share data for two servers but for different scripts on Frappe framework

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I am using Frappe framework. I would like to share same data that is collected from **Sign up** to **POS profile** but keeping in mind that both of them located on different servers. Any advice?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Event Streaming.

> Event Streaming enables inter site communications between two or more
> sites. You can subscribe to Document Types and stream Documents
> between different sites.
>
> For Example: Consider you have more than one Company hosted on
> different sites, one among them is the main site where you want to do
> ledger posting and on other sites, the Sales Invoices are generated.
> You can use Event Streaming in this case. For this, your child company
> sites can subscribe to the main company site for Item, Customer, and
> Supplier Document Types. The main Company in turn can subscribe to the
> child companies for Sales Invoices.

Source: https://docs.erpnext.com/docs/v13/user/manual/en/automation/event_streaming

Comment: if you can get it to work. It really is a mystery